# SQL Trigger & Inserted Idenities

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I've got a problem with a trigger that i can't figure out.

Assume i have two tables, Stu_Table2 & Stu_log.  Stu_table2 has some columns, one of which is an automatically generated primary key [stu_id].  The link between the two tables is [stu_name]=[user_id]

The below code works fine for Updates & Deletions (as the primary key already exists). But i'm stuck on the insert - how can i insert the automatically generated primary key from stu_name to log table if it hasn't been generated yet?

Stu_name columns, [stu_id] [Stu_name] [Stu_class]

Stu_log columns, [user_id] [stu_name]

obviously this isn't a real world example, just testing proof  of concept.

```
    ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[stu_testtrigger]
    ON [dbo].[Stu_Table2] FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
    AS 

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with caller queries SELECT statements.
    -- If an update/insert/delete occurs on the main table, the number of         records         affected
    -- should only be based on that table and not what records the triggers may/may not
    -- select.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --
    -- Variables Needed for this Trigger
    -- 
    DECLARE @stu_ID int
    DECLARE @stu_name varchar(15)
    DECLARE @stu_class int

    --
    -- Determine if this is an INSERT,UPDATE, or DELETE Action
    -- 
    DECLARE @Action as char(1)
    DECLARE @Count as int
    SET @Action = 'I' -- Set Action to 'I'nsert by default.
    SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM DELETED
    if @Count > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @Action = 'D' -- Set Action to 'D'eleted.
            SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED
            IF @Count > 0
                SET @Action = 'U' -- Set Action to 'U'pdated.
        END

    if @Action = 'D'
        -- This is a DELETE Record Action
        --
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Stu_id =[stu_id]
                        ,@Stu_name = [stu_name]
            FROM DELETED

            DELETE [dbo].[stu_log]
            WHERE [user_id]=@stu_id
        END
     Else
        BEGIN
                --
                -- Table INSERTED is common to both the INSERT, UPDATE trigger
                --
                SELECT @stu_id =[stu_id]
                    ,@stu_name = [stu_name]
                FROM INSERTED 

             if @Action = 'I'
                -- This is an Insert Record Action
                --

                --THIS IS WHERE I'm STUCK i think!!!
                BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO [stu_log]
                        ([user_id]
                        ,[description])
                    VALUES
                        (@stu_id
                        ,@stu_name)

                END
            else
                -- This is an Update Record Action
                --
                BEGIN
                    UPDATE [stu_log]
                        SET [user_id] = @stu_id
                              ,[description] = @Stu_name
                        WHERE [user_id]=@stu_id
                END
        END
```

HELP!

Comment: The `inserted` table would contain the value for the primary key column as well. Did you find it unavailable in the `@Action = 'I'` block?

Comment: as @Vikdor said, the Inserted should have the stu_id even if it is an IDENTITY() autogenerated value. What is your exact problem? (error, is it null,or... ?)

Comment: What's the *point* of `stu_log` - it seems to just be a copy of two columns from `stu_table2`, because this trigger will be keeping them in sync. Why not just have a view, if you're trying to hide `stu_class` from something. Also, your trigger is quite broken, because `inserted` can contain multiple rows. That means the result of `SELECT @Var1 = Column1,@Var2 = Column2 from inserted` is not defined. You could even find that the two variables end up with values from different rows (in theory, at least).

Comment: What version of SQLServer? If 2008 you could look at `MERGE`

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to want to carry out distinctly different actions for inserts, updates and deletes, I'm not sure why you're cramming all of the actions into a single trigger. I'd just have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[stu_testtrigger_I]
ON [dbo].[Stu_Table2] AFTER INSERT
AS
   INSERT INTO stu_log ([user_id],[description])
   SELECT stu_id,stu_name from inserted
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[stu_testtrigger_D]
ON [dbo].[Stu_Table2] AFTER DELETE
AS
   DELETE FROM stu_log WHERE [user_id] IN (
   SELECT stu_id from deleted)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[stu_testtrigger_U]
ON [dbo].[Stu_Table2] AFTER UPDATE
AS
   UPDATE l SET user_name = i.user_name
   FROM
      stu_log l
         inner join
      inserted i
         on l.[user_id] = i.stu_id
GO
```

Notes:

1. This works for multi-row inserts, updates and deletes, which your original didn't
2. I've said `AFTER` instead of `FOR`, to make it clearer to you that these actions occur after any activity in `Stu_Table2` has already occurred (e.g. the identity value has already been generated, which seems to be your concern).
3. You should note, however, that `AFTER` and `FOR` are synonymous. You'd only get different behaviour if we were doing an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.
4. I removed the pointless `[user_id] = @stu_id` setting from the `UPDATE`. Given the `WHERE` clause of this update (or my join equivalent, above), those two must already be equal.